How to include pyarmor runtime in cx_freeze executable?
Got this cx freeze setup
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["pyarmor_runtime_000000", "os", "sys", "hashlib", "json", "time", "logging", "subprocess", "traceback", "paramiko", "PyQt5"],
    "excludes": [],
    # "includes": [r'dist\pyarmor_runtime_000000']
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

# Define the executable
executables = [
    Executable("dist/patcher-source.py", base=base, target_name="Awakening2-Patcher.exe", icon='patcher-icon.ico')
]

setup(
    name="Awakening2-Patcher",
    version="1.0",
    description="Auto Patcher for Awakening2",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables
)


Problem is I m trying to obfuscate my py file with pyarmor, generating steps are:
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    os.chdir(script_dir)

    os.system('pyarmor gen .\patcher-source.py')
    os.system('python setup.py build')

Problem is i dont know how to properly include dist/pyarmor_runtime_000000, tried adding it to "includes" key, no luck, to packages also, but it raises module not found.
for contenxt 'pyarmor_runtime_000000' is a directory containing an init.py:
# Pyarmor 8.5.8 (trial), 000000, 2024-05-17T12:37:57.872232
from .pyarmor_runtime import __pyarmor__

And a pyarmor_runtime.pyd
